# Proper action for EF Core onDelete in followers functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a practice app with .NET 6 and EF Core and I'm trying to implement a followers system. However I'm having issues with setting up the `onDelete` for the join-table:

This is my Profile class:

```
public class Profile {
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Email { get; set; }
 public ICollection<ProfileFollowing> Followers { get; set; }
 public ICollection<ProfileFollowing> Followings { get; set; }
}
```

And this Is my Join Table, which keeps records of the followings:

```
public class ProfileFollowing {
 public int ObserverId { get; set; }
 public Profile Observer { get; set; }
 public int TargetId { get; set; }
 public Profile Target { get; set; }
}
```

I'm setting this up in my model builder the following way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProfileFollowing>(profileFollowing =>
{
 profileFollowing
 .HasOne(o => o.Observer)
 .WithMany(p => p.Followings)
 .HasForeignKey(o => o.ObserverId)
 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

 profileFollowing
 .HasOne(t => t.Target)
 .WithMany(p => p.Followers)
 .HasForeignKey(t => t.TargetId)
 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

 profileFollowing.HasIndex(pf => new {pf.ObserverId, pf.TargetId}).IsUnique();
});
```

However, apparently SQL Server does not like when both on the `onDelete` are marked as cascades as this **May Cause Cycles Or Multiple Cascade Paths**. The idea of multiple cascades is that when I delete a `Profile` it may attempt to delete the same records in my `ProfileFollowings` table twice, right?

Well is there any workaround for this? I see the very same implementation (i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499265/followers-schema-in-entity-framework) or [a similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582268/entity-framework-core-fluent-api-many-to-many)), however nobody mentions the issues with deleting the records. I want to be sure that if I delete a `Profile`, the `ProfileFollowings` will update correctly and all of the other `Profiles` will have their followers/followings adjusted.

**PS**: I know one workaround would be to set one of the FK (`TargetId`/`ObserverId`) to `null` and set `onDelete` action to be `SetNull`, but this way my unique index on `ObserverId` & `TargetId` becomes useless.